# Generate same object from yaml

Tags: yaml

I have a class which generated from YAML.
This class generated 10 times.
I want that 3 of the instances of the class will be the same object.
I know that I can generate father to the three but there is a better way?
I am using java (spring boot)

Comment: Please show us your code. We can't help you if you not even tell us which programming language you're using.

Comment: @flyx added the programming language (java, spring boot).
This is a general problem, I don't think the code is really relevant.

Comment: If this is a general problem, you have to describe it better. I cannot deduce from the question what you're trying to do (e.g. *father* is not a common term. It is unclear what you mean by „generated 10 times“). The language matters for example because in some languages, a class instance has reference semantics (Java, C#), while in others it has not (C++, Ada) and that has consequences on instances being *the same object*.